# How can i check date input validity?

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation, date, input

I'm using `AngularJS` and `Onsen-ui` for creating a mobile page that contain an input in which the user should fill in with a valid date. Here is my code:

**HTML:**

`<input type="date" autofocus class="search-input" name="dateInput" ng-model="date" ng-keyup="checkDate()"/>`

**JS:**

```
    function checkDateFn() {
      if (Object.prototype.toString.call($scope.date) === '[object Date]') {
        // it is a date
        if (isNaN($scope.date.getTime())) {  // d.valueOf() could also work
          // date is not valid
        }
        else {
          // date is valid
          // DO SOMETHING
        }
      }
      else {
        // not a date
      }
    }
```

But it doesn't get a valid date (i do not know the why).
I also tried to use HTML `form`, and i wrote this:

```
    <form name="dateForm">
      <input type="date" autofocus class="search-input" name="dateInput" ng-model="date"/>
    </form>
```

But in this case i do not know how to trigger a function when `dateForm.dateInput.$valid` occurs.

Do you have a better way to reach my purpose?

Comment: It's dirty, but you could always set up a `$watch( 'dateForm.dateInput.$valid', watchHandler) `.  There's probably a much simpler way though.

Comment: I do not know why but the `watchHandler` is triggered since the begin, on first page load. Does `dateForm.dateInput.$valid` check for date validity or just that the field is filled?

Comment: you can use ng-pattern for this.

Comment: `dateForm.dateInput.$valid` check the validity when the input value is changed, see this [plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/6EQ7eCAWsk6eYTOhQdOp?p=preview)

Comment: Yes, but it should trigger the function only when it is valid, not on every change. Am i right?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the form submit button until `dateForm.$invalid`

So on your submit button you could add `ng-disabled="dateForm.$invalid"`

Comment: so when do you want the validation to occur?

Comment: When user inserts a valid date.

Comment: Yes but what do you want to achieve with the validation? 

You could show some error message until the input is valid with something like `ng-show="dateForm.dateInput.$error"`

Comment: When the validation is ok i want to do this: `$scope.sharedData.docDate = $filter('date')(new Date($scope.date), 'dd/MM/yyyy');`

Comment: what is it that you want to do exactly with the date? Send it to a server or simply display it again in another section of the page?

Comment: Display it in another section of the page

Comment: Then you might as well set the ng-model of the input to `sharedData.docDate` and where you want to show it `{{ sharedData.docDate | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy' }}`

Comment: It does the trick: it shows the div of the date only when the user insert a valid date. If the user inserts an invalid date the div is not displayed, but if the user inserts an invalid date after a valid date, the div doesn't disappear. Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/kNRKTX0v

Comment: It wont disappear until you remove it from your data object because of 2 way databinding. 
I find it quite hard to understand what it is you want to achieve. Could you possibly share a complete jsfiddle or similar with us?